# Trying to find the Theme for this Magento site

Tags: magento2, theme

A client has said they like the look of this website, which is built with Magento. I am wondering  if anyone recognises the theme that is being used?

https://www.ripcurl.com/us/

Any help locating this is very much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is just a custom theme,
you can build this from any theme that is looks alike. even from `Luma` or `blank`,
but if you like to get more prebuilt templates, blocks, widgets etc

this for example:

> https://athlete2.com/ca

create child theme and adjust your modifications.